# Why is a program that updates a large static floating point array slower in Rust than in C?

Tags: c, performance, rust

I wrote a simple program to compare Rust and C performance.

The Rust version:

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

const STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE: usize = 10000000;
static mut A: [f64; STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE] = [1.0; STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE];

fn main() {
    let now = Instant::now();

    unsafe {
        for i in 0..STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE {
            A[i] = 2.0E0 * A[i];
        }
    }

    let duration = now.elapsed();
    println!("{}", (duration.as_secs() * 1_000_000_000 + duration.subsec_nanos() as u64) / 1000);
}
```

Run it in debug & release mode:

```
$ ./target/debug/calc
472046 us.
$ ./target/release/calc
62860 us.
```

The release version has a drastic performance gain compared to debug.

The C version does the same thing and runs on the same server:

```c
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE   10000000

static double A[STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE];
int mysecond(void)
{
        struct timeval tp;
        struct timezone tzp;
        int i;

        i = gettimeofday(&tp,&tzp);
        return (tp.tv_sec * 1000000 + tp.tv_usec);
}

int main(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
    {
        A[j] = 1.0;
    }

    int t = mysecond();
    for (j = 0; j < STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
    {
        A[j] = 2.0E0 * A[j];
    }
    printf("%d us.\n", mysecond() - t);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it with `-O0` and `-O2`:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
41626 us.
$ gcc -O2 test.c
$ ./a.out
13499 us.
```

The Rust optimized version only compares to `gcc -O0`, and is very weak compared to `gcc -O2`. Is this reasonable? How can I improve the performance of the Rust version?

Comment: Have you tried comparing the assembly for your two versions of the C program?  Chances are that your loop is never executed, because it has no effect on your program's output.

Comment: @paddy update to global variables are side effects. I am not sure any compiler would optimize that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust compiles the loop to:

```
.LBB0_1:
    movupd  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax - 48]
    movupd  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax - 32]
    addpd   xmm0, xmm0
    addpd   xmm1, xmm1
    movupd  xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax - 48], xmm0
    movupd  xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax - 32], xmm1
    movupd  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax - 16]
    movupd  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax]
    addpd   xmm0, xmm0
    addpd   xmm1, xmm1
    movupd  xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax - 16], xmm0
    movupd  xmmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax], xmm1
    add rax, 8
    cmp rax, 100006
    jne .LBB0_1
```

While GCC 7.1.0 compiles to:

```
L6:
    movsd   (%rbx), %xmm0
    addq    $8, %rbx
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbx)
    cmpq    %rbp, %rbx
    jne     L6
```

Rust puts the array in a data section, while C actually writes (`memset` with pattern) to the memory. This means that your OS running the app likely just maps the range and relies on virtual memory to do the right thing.

If you change the code to run the same loop before the measurement, the runtime goes down considerably. It's actually faster than the C version on my machine. (possibly due to that loop unrolling)

```rust
unsafe {
    for i in 0..STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE {
        A[i] = 2.0E0 * A[i];
    }
}

let now = Instant::now();

unsafe {
    for i in 0..STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE {
        A[i] = 2.0E0 * A[i];
    }
}

let duration = now.elapsed();
```

Comment: "`If you change the code to run the same loop before the measurement, the runtime goes down considerably. It's actually faster than the C version on my machine.`". Sorry, I can't catch your meaning. Could you explain it? Thx!

Comment: @NanXiao added the example

Comment: I compile the `C` program using `Clang`, and the performance is as good as `gcc` compiler.

Comment: @NanXiao Yeah, I should've just removed it instead. There were a few bad assumptions there.

Comment: `Another thing I missed is that Rust puts the array in a data section, while C actually writes (memset with pattern) to the memory.`. I have little confused about this explanation. I think `C` also puts the global array in data section. Could you elaborate it? Thx!

Comment: @NanXiao It doesn't. Compile with `gcc -O2 -S ...` and you'll see the initial values created via `_memset_pattern16` or similar. Rust just embeds the repeating values in the data section. `rustc --emit asm ...`

Comment: Sorry I still can't get your point. Per my understanding, data section will also reside in memory. Right? So every operation will finally update the data in array which in memory.

Comment: What rust does is put the actual values of the array one after another in the resulting binary it compiles. So when you start the binary, they may not even be completely read from the disk yet. When you read them for the first time, they may causes page faults that need to be handled. C instead initialises the whole array in a loop at the start, so by the time you get to your loop, the range is definitely allocated and written to. Compile both with the commands I showed before and see the end of the resulting file.

Comment: I get your point. `for (j = 0; j < STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE; j++) { A[j] = 1.0; }` in `C` program will load array from disk to memory, so in the second calculation loop, the speed will definitely fast.

Comment: You could put in the first sentence of your answer something saying that rust is not at fault and the benchmark is incorrect :). So after first look at your answer one does not get the incorrect impression.